# LibGDX switching between screens causes UI buttons not to load properly

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx

I am currently creating a multiple screen setup for my LibGDX project using Stage, Button, addListener and Screen. I create a stage for the whole game and add buttons to that with listeners. The listeners send the user to another screen when clicking the buttons. It looks as follows:
[Menu Screen #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9JjY.png)

Then when I click login, it correctly sends me to the login screen, where I have menu button to go back, but the button looks as follows:
[Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHaHG.png)

The button is still clickable and will return you to the menu when clicked on, but should look the same as the previous buttons. Also when I go back to the menu, it looks like this: 
[Menu Screen #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3pzP.png)

My code for the menu screen is:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    Gdx.graphics.setTitle("Menu");
    Button startButton = game.inputFactory.createButton("Start", 0, 150, 300, 50);
    Button loginButton = game.inputFactory.createButton("Login", 0, 220, 300, 50);
    Button signUpButton = game.inputFactory.createButton("Sign Up", 0, 290, 300, 50);

    game.inputFactory.onClickGoTo(startButton, game, new GameScreen(game));
    game.inputFactory.onClickGoTo(loginButton, game, new LoginScreen(game));
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.end();
    game.stage.draw();
}
```

My code for the login screen is:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    game.inputFactory.clearStage();
    game.stage.clear();
    Gdx.graphics.setTitle("Login");
    Button menuButton = game.inputFactory.createButton("Menu", 0, 150, 300, 50);
    game.inputFactory.onClickGoTo(menuButton, game, new MenuScreen(game));
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    game.batch.begin();
    game.font32.draw(game.batch, "Login", Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - 50, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 30);
    game.batch.end();
    game.stage.draw();
}
```

Where onClickGoTo adds a clickListener to the buttons with redirection to the new screen.
And where inputFactory is a class where I create buttons with preset skins.

I assumed it had something to do with drawing the stage, but I am not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have got the wrong look on the libgdx stage class. I have encountered the same mistake when i was learning.

You should have different stages for each screen.

> Your **MenuScreen** has his own *stage* with the **menu buttons**.
>
> And your **LoginScreen** has his own *stage* with the **login buttons**

This means that in your screen constructor you create your separate stage and add the wanted buttons.

## Menuscreen:

`menustage.add(startButton);`
`menustage.add(startButton);`
`menustage.add(signUpButton );`

## LoginScreen:

`loginstage.add(menuButton);`

---

This problem has got me writing far to complex code but when it the libgdx classes were clear to me it made alot of sense.

You can use different stages for a screen wich gives the freedom to give your screen different views!

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful! :)

Comment: Glad i could help! You should also add The click listners at The constructor. Beacause the show method can be called more then once. For example if you minimize the app and reopen it. This wil create a new button and listener each time if you leave your code in the show() method.